# Sieve of Eratosthenes : SIGSEGV?

Tags: c

I have written the code for the sieve but the program runs for only array size less than or equal to 1000000. For the rest of the cases which are larger, a simple SIGSEGV occurs. Can this be made to run cases > 1000000. Or where am I wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    unsigned long long int arr[10000001] = {[0 ... 10000000] = 0};
    unsigned long long int c=0,i,j,a,b;
    scanf("%llu%llu",&a,&b);
    for(i=2;i<=b;i++)
        if(arr[i] == 0)
            for(j=2*i;j<=b;j+=i)
                arr[j] = 1;
    for(i=(a>2)?a:2;i<=b;i++)
    if(arr[i] == 0)``
        c++;
    printf("%llu",c);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Related: You do realize (or by the looks of it you don't) that the data *in* a sieve of eratosthenes can literally be *bits*, (use `unsigned char` if you don't want to do the bit-offset math)? Think about it. its a *flags* array, thats all. Its the *indicies* to that array that you really care about. There is *no* reason to be storing 64-bit values when all you care about is whether they are zero or non-zero.

Comment: Relax: SIGSEGV is the last prime.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes sir, I realized it. Plain stupidity to store 0/1 in unsigned long long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line allocates memory on the stack (which is a limited resource)

```
unsigned long long int arr[10000001] = {[0 ... 10000000] = 0};
```

If you are allocating 10,000,000 entries at 4 bytes each, that is 40 million bytes, which will be more than your stack can handle.

(or, on your platform, there is a good chance that a long-long-int is 8 or more bytes, indicating 80 million bytes in use!)

Instead, allocate the memory from the heap, which is much more plentiful:

```
int* arr = malloc(10,000,000 * sizeof(int));  // commas for clarity only. Remove in real code!
```

Or, if you want the memory initialized to zero, use [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

Then at the end of your program be sure you also free it:

```
free(arr);
```

**PS**  The syntax `{[0 ... 10000000] = 0};` is needlessly verbose.
To initialize an array to zero, simply:

```
int arr[100] = {0};  // Thats all!
```

Comment: ... or jam it in global memory outside of `main()`. Either way.

Comment: It can stay local, it just has to not be on the stack.  Adding a `static` will fix it too.

Comment: @abelenky - that's a GCC extension to set an array range.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits  In OP's case, it could just be `{ 0 }`.

Comment: @abelenky-thanks a lot! The syntax{[0 .. } initializes all array elements to zero.

Answer (score 5):

You declared an array that can hold 10000001 items; if you want to handle larger numbers, you need a bigger array.  I'm mildly surprised that it works for 1000000 already - that's a lot of stack space to be using.

Edit:  sorry - didn't notice you had a different number of zeroes there.  Don't use the stack to allocate your array and you should be fine.  Just add `static` to the array declaration and you'll probably be okay.